# what does description of `container parameter for function onCreateView of fragment class` mean?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

The description of [container parameter for function onCreateView of fragment class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) says :

*container :    If non-null, this is the parent view that the fragment's UI should be attached to. The fragment should not add the view itself, but this can be used to generate the LayoutParams of the view.*

does the line

*The fragment should not add the view itself, but this can be used to generate the LayoutParams of the view*

mean that `container.addView(some_view)` is not permitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. You would use this parameter in a call to `inflate()` on a `LayoutInflater` (e.g., `inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);`) or to determine what `LayoutParams` are needed if you are creating your fragment contents directly via Java instead of inflation. Otherwise, the container is owned by the hosting activity, and your fragment should leave it alone, AFAIK.